# Show that this wreath product is representable by matrices.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, wreath-product

We know that every finitely generated metabelian group $\Gamma$ has a faithful representation over a finite product of fields.
Denoting $C_n$ the cyclic group of order $n$,   the restricted wreath product $C_6\wr C_\infty$ is linear over a product of two fields ( a field of char. 2 and a field of char. 3). May I ask how to construct this injective homomorphism from $C_6\wr C_\infty$ to the product of general linear group?

Let $t$ be the generator for $C_\infty$ and $s$ be the generator for $C_6$, I know that $C_6\wr C_\infty = \langle s, t \rangle$, but I am not sure where the generator should be mapped to. Any hint/reference would be really appreciated.

Comment: Since your wreath product appears to be finitely generated, I am  guessing that you are talking about the restricted wreath product, but with wreath products with an infinite top group you need to make that clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "the product of general linear group"? Do you simply mean $GL(n, R)$ for some $n$ and some commutative ring $R$?

Comment: Choose the Laurent ring $(\mathbf{Z}/6\mathbf{Z})[u,u^{-1}]$ (a product of two domains, hence embeddable into a product of two fields). Then embed as $s\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, $t\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}u& 0 \\ 0 & u^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you, Yves